# How to make php "substr" ignore code for images?

Tags: php, substr

On my website, I have a code to cut off a long string of text using php's "substr" method. However, if there is code for an image in the string, it sometimes cuts it off in the middle of the code for the image, causing the image not to display properly?

How can I fix this?

Comment: We need to see your code to be able to offer you any advice at all.

Comment: @Michael He's trimming a string of HTML to a certain length using `substr()`. What more do you need to know?

Comment: @Blazemonger We need to know what he has tried sofar, how the code is structured, any possible quirks and/or improvements that can be made, etc.

Answer (score 3):

How about calling [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on the text before using `substr`? If you also need to remove entities, you could also remove them with a simple regex or add [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to the mix.

Example:

```
substr(strip_tags($text), 0, 10);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a function I have used before:

```
function trimHTML($text, $max_length) {
    $tags = array();
    $result = "";

    $is_open = false;
    $grab_open = false;
    $is_close = false;
    $in_double_quotes = false;
    $in_single_quotes = false;
    $tag = "";

    $i = 0;
    $stripped = 0;

    $stripped_text = strip_tags($text);

    while ($i < strlen($text) && $stripped < strlen($stripped_text) && $stripped < $max_length) {
        $symbol = $text{$i};
        $result .= $symbol;

        switch ($symbol) {
            case '<':
                $is_open = true;
                $grab_open = true;
                break;

            case '"':
                if ($in_double_quotes)
                    $in_double_quotes = false;
                else
                    $in_double_quotes = true;

                break;

            case "'":
                if ($in_single_quotes)
                    $in_single_quotes = false;
                else
                    $in_single_quotes = true;

                break;

            case '/':
                if ($is_open && !$in_double_quotes && !$in_single_quotes) {
                    $is_close = true;
                    $is_open = false;
                    $grab_open = false;
                }

                break;

            case ' ':
                if ($is_open)
                    $grab_open = false;
                else
                    $stripped++;

                break;

            case '>':
                if ($is_open) {
                    $is_open = false;
                    $grab_open = false;
                    array_push($tags, $tag);
                    $tag = "";
                } else if ($is_close) {
                    $is_close = false;
                    array_pop($tags);
                    $tag = "";
                }

                break;

            default:
                if ($grab_open || $is_close)
                    $tag .= $symbol;

                if (!$is_open && !$is_close)
                    $stripped++;
        }

        $i++;
    }

    while ($tags) {
        $result .= "</" . array_pop($tags) . ">";
    }

    return $result;
};
```